# Need to edit cells in column C if they have a " at the end

Tags: excel, vba

In column C there will be several different values, If the cells have a " at the end i need to remove it.

```
If .Cells(rw, 3).Value Like "*"*" Then
```

Not sure what to put in the "Then"

Comment: You need to escape your quotes, for example `Like "*""" Then`.  Or, perhaps `If Right(.Cells(rw,3).Value,1) = Chr(34) Then`

Answer (score 6):

I would do it like that

```
If Right(.Cells(rw, 3).Value, 1) = Chr(34) Then
    .Cells(rw, 3).Value = Left(.Cells(rw, 3).Value, Len(.Cells(rw, 3).Value) - 1)
End If
```

Comment: the ```.Cells``` is getting a invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: I just took your code and assumed that it is embedded in a `with .. end with` construct. If not you need to post more than the one line of your code you posted.

Comment: Oh ya im dumb... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: How would i do the same thing but with a space? ```With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rwChr1 = 1000 To 2 Step -1
        If Right(.Cells(rwChr1, 2).Value, 1) = Chr(32) Then
            .Cells(rwChr1, 3).Value = Left(.Cells(rwChr1, 3).Value, Len(.Cells(rwChr1, 3).Value) - 1)
        End If

            Next rwChr1
        End With```

Comment: Thats what i tried but im getting an invalid procedure call or argument error

Comment: You have a 2 in the if condition: `If Right(.Cells(rwChr1, 2).Value, 1)` but a 3 in  `Left(.Cells(rwChr1, 3).Value, Len(.Cells(rwChr1, 3).Value) - 1)` i.e. you check the 2nd column but try to change the third one.